# How to set the color of the background in multiple plot in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

How to set the color of the background in multiple plot in gnuplot? I tried the following script:

```
reset
set encoding iso_8859_1                                         
set terminal pngcairo size 1400,800 font "Serif CMU,15" enhanced  
set output "figure.png"                                 


Row1 = "set tmargin screen 0.92; set bmargin screen 0.40"   # Top and bottom margins
Row2 = "set tmargin screen 0.40; set bmargin screen 0.20"
Col1 = "set lmargin screen 0.10; set rmargin screen 0.50"   # Left and right margins
Col2 = "set lmargin screen 0.50; set rmargin screen 0.88"

# Multiplot option with main title
set multiplot layout 2,2 rowsfirst 

@Row1; @Col1                            # Calling the macros
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb '#F6DEBE' fillstyle solid noborder
plot 'blue.txt' 


@Row1; @Col2

set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb '#F6DEBE' fillstyle solid noborder
plot 'blue.txt' 


@Row2; @Col1

set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb '#F6DEBE' fillstyle solid noborder
plot 'blue.txt' 

@Row2; @Col2

set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb '#F6DEBE' fillstyle solid noborder
plot 'blue.txt'
```

I also tried to set unset object 1 after each plot.

I obtained:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you checked `help pngcairo`?

> Syntax:
>
> ```
>     set term pngcairo
>                  {{no}enhanced} {mono|color}
>                  {{no}transparent} {{no}crop} {background <rgbcolor>
> ```

So, something like the following should do the job, unless you have some special wishes.

```
set term pngcairo background 0xf6debe
```

**Addition:**

If you want to set different backgrounds for the graphs you can either set a rectangle behind the full graph or part of the screen.
However, although there should be the option `noborder`, I haven't managed to plot the rectangles without border. I don't know what I am missing.

**Code:** (colored graph background)

```
### different colored backgrounds for each graph
reset session

set multiplot layout 2,2
    set grid x,y

    set obj 1 rect from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb 0xffdddd behind
    plot x

    set obj 1 rect from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb 0xddffdd behind
    plot x**2

    set obj 1 rect from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb 0xddddff behind
    plot cos(x)

    set obj 1 rect from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 fc rgb 0xffffdd behind
    plot sin(x)/x

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Code:** (colored backgrounds for part of canvas/screen)

```
### colored backgrounds in multiplot
reset session

set multiplot layout 2,2

    set obj 1 rect from screen 0.0,0.5 to screen 0.5,1.0 fc rgb 0xffeeee behind
    plot x

    set obj 1 rect from screen 0.5,0.5 to screen 1.0,1.0 fc rgb 0xeeffee behind
    plot x**2

    set obj 1 rect from screen 0.0,0.0 to screen 0.5,0.5 fc rgb 0xeeeeff behind
    plot cos(x)

    set obj 1 rect from screen 0.5,0.0 to screen 1.0,0.5 fc rgb 0xffffee behind
    plot sin(x)/x

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much